# Loop URL and store info in R

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a for loop that will loop through many websites and extract a few elements, and store the results in a table in R. Here's my go so far, just not sure how to start the for loop, or copy all results into one variable to be exported later.

```
library("dplyr")
library("rvest")
library("leaflet")
library("ggmap")


url <- c(html("http://www.webiste_name.com/")

agent <- html_nodes(url,"h1 span")
fnames<-html_nodes(url, "#offNumber_mainLocContent span")
address <- html_nodes(url,"#locStreetContent_mainLocContent")

scrape<-t(c(html_text(agent),html_text(fnames),html_text(address)))


View(scrape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with `lapply`.

The code would look something like this:

```
library("rvest")
library("dplyr")

#a vector of urls you want to scrape
URLs <- c("http://...1", "http://...2", ....)

df <- lapply(URLs, function(u){

      html.obj <- read_html(u)
      agent <- html_nodes(html.obj,"h1 span") %>% html_text
      fnames<-html_nodes(html.obj, "#offNumber_mainLocContent span") %>% html_text
      address <- html_nodes(html.obj,"#locStreetContent_mainLocContent") %>% html_text

     data.frame(Agent=agent, Fnames=fnames, Address=address)
})

df <- do.all(rbind, df)

View(df)
```

Comment: Worked great! How can I adjust to make sure the data from each scrape is stored in a seperate row? Right now its storing them all adjacent to eachother

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question. within the data.frame of `lapply` you could have the following `data.frame(Agent=agent, Fnames=fnames, Address=address, URL=u) ` to have the corresponding url to every line generated

Comment: I figured it out, but another question, why would I get an error like this when trying to search a site

"error: 'www.website.com' does not exist in current working directory"

Answer (score 2):

Given that your question isn't fully reproducible, here's a toy example that loops through three URLs (Red Socks, Jays and Yankees):

```
library(rvest)

# teams
teams <- c("BOS", "TOR", "NYY")

# init
df <- NULL

# loop
for(i in teams){
    # find url
    url <- paste0("http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/", i, "/")
    page <- read_html(url)
    # grab table
    table <- page %>%
        html_nodes(css = "#franchise_years") %>%
        html_table() %>%
        as.data.frame()
    # bind to dataframe
    df <- rbind(df, table)
}

# view captured data
View(df)
```

The loop works because it replaces `i` in `paste0` with each team in sequence.