# Is there a way to save multiple files during a loop from the same string?

Tags: python

I am running a loop through an excel document and trying to save a different text file for each row in the excel. I want to do this with the same naming format

I have tried to do an f-string which gave me a syntax error or to save the files as follows:

```
endfile1 = (r"C:\Users\jrwaller\Documents\Automated Eve\Raw Data for {projectNum}.eve")
```

An example of the for loop for naming the files is:

```
for i in range (10, finalrow, 1):

    projectNum = sheet.cell(i,1).value  #assigns project number
    print(projectNum)                                           #test
    #sets up file string names for later
    endfile1 = (r"C:\Users\jrwaller\Documents\Automated Eve\ITP19_Y02_F1_2018-10-03 {projectNum}.eve")
```

So that later I can (with newBaseCase and longstr1 previously defined):

```
      with open(longStr1) as old_file:
            with open(endfile1, "w") as new_file:
                for line in old_file:
                    if "BASE CASE" in line:
                        line = newBaseCase + line
                    new_file.write(line)
```

I am hoping so that if excel has two lines of projects, it will save a 
Raw Data for `Proj1.txt` and Raw Data for `Proj2.txt` (where "ProjX" is taken form excel, but as currently set up it currently saves one file named Raw Data for `{projectNum}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop URL and store info in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646675/loop-url-and-store-info-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.format()` to replace `{projectNum}` with the variable.

```
endfile1 = r"C:\Users\jrwaller\Documents\Automated Eve\ITP19_Y02_F1_2018-10-03 {projectNum}.eve".format(projectNum=ProjectNum)
```

or you can use an f-string, which automatically interpolates variables.

```
endfile1 = fr"C:\Users\jrwaller\Documents\Automated Eve\ITP19_Y02_F1_2018-10-03 {projectNum}.eve"
```

Answer (score 0):

f-strings are prepended with `f`; you're only using a raw string, which is prepended with `r`

Thus, for `endfile1`, do the following instead:

```py
endfile1 = fr"C:\Users\jrwaller\Documents\Automated Eve\ITP19_Y02_F1_2018-10-03 {projectNum}.eve"
```

Comment: he needs it to be raw as well, because of the backslashes.

Comment: Many thanks, forgot about that for some reason. Fixed my answer